# Export from Mac Photos app to folders by date ("YYYY-MM-DD")

Tags: applescript, export, photos

I'm attempting to get all my pictures out of the iPhotos and Photos app.
I found this script to export all the pictures from iPhotos. But it doesn't work when i change it to use the Photos app.

```
set destination to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to pictures folder)
tell application "iPhoto"
    repeat with i in (get selection)
        tell i to my copyPhoto(date, image path, title, destination)
    end repeat
end tell

on copyPhoto(d, p, t, dest) -- the name of the file is the title of the photo in iPhoto, date format for folder name = 2014-09-25
tell d to set d to "" & its year & "-" & text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & ((its month) as integer)) & "-" & text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & its day)
    try -- create folder if neccessary, check to not overwrite any files in the subfolder, copy the file, rename with the title
        do shell script "f=" & d & ";t=" & (quoted form of t) & ";tFile=" & (quoted form of p) & "; e=${tFile##*.}; cd " & dest & ";mkdir -p \"$f\"; while [ -e \"$f/$t.$e\" ];do  t=\"$t _\";done; cp -a \"$tFile\" \"$f/$t.$e\""
    end try
end copyPhoto
```

(from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6565154?start=0&tstart=0)

Would someone be able to help me figure out how to do this with the Photos app?
The format that the script uses it perfect, pictures organized by folder:

2014-12-30
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
...

THANKS!!!!

Comment: Apple dropped the `image path` property in Photos.app. That's why the script doesn't compile.

Comment: so, is there no way to get the image path in Photos.app?

Comment: You could use the `export` command but this requires extra logic to handle renaming and preventing from being overwritten

Answer (score 1):

Vadian is right, no "image path" in Photos (thanks Apple !), so must use Export. see script bellow which does this, also formatting date and creating folder if required.

```
set TopFolder to (path to desktop folder from user domain) as string -- your main destination folder

tell application "Photos"
repeat with aPhoto in (get selection)
    set SName to filename of aPhoto
    set theDate to date of aPhoto
    -- convert date to string yyyy-mm-dd
    set SY to (year of theDate) as string
    set SM to text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & ((month of theDate) as integer))
    set SD to text -2 thru -1 of ("0" & ((day of theDate) as string))
    set DestFolder to SY & "-" & SM & "-" & SD -- DestFolder = folder "date" 

    -- check if folder  DestFolder exists : if not creation
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (folder (TopFolder & DestFolder) exists) then
            make new folder in TopFolder with properties {name:DestFolder}
        end if
    end tell

    -- you may have to add a check if file (TopFolder & DestFolder & SName) already exists
    -- and take appropriate action (add index, add word "copy",...)
    export {aPhoto} to (TopFolder & DestFolder)
end repeat
end tell
```

During tests, I discovered that Photos is much slower than iPhoto. Just to get Date or filename property it takes time ! Also "Export" does. the script itself could be optimized using shell functions for date formatting or folder check/creation (I am not shell expert), but the speed bottleneck remains Photos !